# In NetSuite how to write a script for authorize return button on the basis of bill..?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

It's a question related to netsuite and javascript, as well as suitescripts too. In this question i need a hint about how to create a new button in netsuite script and source code would be better if anyone can explain in less code.......:)

Answer (score 2):

In a **Suitlet script**

```
var form = nlapiCreateForm('Form Title');
form.addSubmitButton('Proceed');
```

In a **userevent script**

```
function beforeLoadFunction(type, form){
  form.addButton('custpage_btn_btnaction', 'Button Action');
}
```

Comment: hey Saqiib first of all thx for answering my question, well i want to know if we have bill payment paid in the netsuite on the basis of saved search then after paying that i want to add a button for authorized return button if you know about it xplain..!

Comment: @AshishKumar, Please add details to make it clear. If the detail exceeds the scope of current question than post a new question for it.

Comment: @Saquib thx for concern now i am able to do it. and i am not having problem regarding this...well if you dont mind can you give me your mail id because i am new in netsuite.So if you are not having problem with this.